# Report Builder 3.0 Updating Parameter Panel

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that has StartDt, and EndDt as parameters. When a user leaves these blank, I default StartDt to yesterday, and EndDt to today. That works fine the the actual parameter send to SQL. But is there a way to update the SSRS Parameter Panel to show the user what dates were defaulted?

I know I could just make the parms required, but I'd rather default the dates like this so users can just put in there account(s) and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default value expressions for each date parameter using the standard date/time functions.

You can set today as:

```
=Today()
```

Yesterday as:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Today())
```

See [How to: Add, Change, or Delete Default Values for a Report Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281306%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for more details.

**Edit after comments**

Say you have the following parameters:

[image]

*StartDt* and *EndDt* are just set up as **Date/Time**:

[image]

Set the **Default Values** expression for each parameter using the expressions above, i.e. `=Today()` and `=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Today())`:

[image]

Now, when you load the report for the first time the two parameters are already populated with the **Default Values**:

[image]

Users can then just leave the dates as the defaults as they're already set, or change them as necessary.

Comment: That really isn't what I asked at all. I said that works fine when sent to SQL. I want the parameter panel updated with that date.

Comment: This is setting defaults at the report level, not in the database code - when you set defaults at the parameter level these are displayed in the parameter panel. They are not left blank, as you say in your question, rather they are pre-populated and displayed without user intervention. Isn't that what you wanted? I'm sorry this didn't help you.

Comment: Ok.. what i have in the expression is this: =code.FormatDateToString(Parameters!StartDt.Value). So if a user puts in a blank it will default to the date I want. It does not update in the parm panel.

Comment: I've added some screenshots that describe the Books Online link above. Hopefully this shows what I was trying to explain.

Comment: I'll take a look, thank you. My apologies for snapping earlier, just having a bad day.

Comment: Don't worry about it! Let me know if my suggestion helps.

Comment: That works for me. I originally wanted the dates to show after the apply button was pressed, in case the user took out the date. But Defaulting to the dates works.